# fail2ban not working with regex (ssh)

Tags: regex, ssh, freebsd

my log file shows this message:

```
Jul 24 06:09:36 myserver sshd[46098]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for
95.58.255.62.static.telecom.kz [95.58.255.62] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
```

regex on ssh filter:

```
^%(__prefix_line)sreverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for .* \[<HOST>\] failed - POSSIB
^%(__prefix_line)sAddress <HOST> .* POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!\s*$
```

they don't working, fail2ban not detect any action.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it is in two lines, should be in one (at least in ubuntu, so my guess in freebsd same).

I am using this in my /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf

```
^%(__prefix_line)sreverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for .* \[<HOST>\] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!\s*$
```

After just check with tool: fail2ban-regex